# Anonymous file from Azure Devops Repo

Tags: azure-devops

I have a private repo in Azure DevOps, and I'd like to expose a file to the internet (a JSON catalog) for everybody with a link to access.

Is that possible?
Do I need to create a public repo to do that? Does it even work with a public repo?

I know this can be done in github, I didn't find a way to do that in ADO.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no such method can expose one file of the private repo to public in Azure DevOps Service.

And if your Azure DevOps Project is private, all Repos in the project are private. We also cannot set one of the repos to public.

For a workaround, you need to create an additional Project and set the new project to **Public** in **Project Settings -> Overview**.

Then you can create a new repo to save the single file(JSON catalog). The new Public repo(contain one file) can accessed by public users directly through the URL.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Change project visibility to public or private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/make-project-public?view=azure-devops)

> Hub / Settings  Nonmember access

> Repos (Code)    read

I can fully understand your requirement.  You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to make single file in repo public. You can change the settings to make the entire repo public. Then your code will be visible for non-logged in people [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/make-project-public?view=azure-devops). As an alternative option, could prepare pipeline to run after every push and publish your single file to Azure Storage Account (or different hosting) or to update file in a new repo in public project in ADO. Of course you can open suggestion to create new feature for ADO, but rather such functionality will not be prepared in a reasonable time, if at all, so apart from opening the request, I recommend implementing the workaround

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I want only one file to be visible and accessible

Comment: So it's not possible, but you could prepare pipeline to publish your single file to Azure Storage Account or different hosting after every push